# Import[] exception possibly caused by ToString[] behaviour which I cannot explain

Tags: import, string-manipulation

Let me just start by pointing out I'm a new StackExchange user as well as a new Mathematica user (started today!) I mention this as a context to my ineptitude :)

I am attempting to read through a list with the names of files I want to open, import data from them and plot that data. Here is the code I'm trying to use:

```
testfiles = ({"aspirina.txt", "silicio.txt", "silicio20.txt", 
   "silicio20luz.txt", "tio2.txt", "vidro.txt", "vidro2.txt"})

Do[{data = Import[path <> ToString[i, StandardForm], {"Table"}], 
  Print[path <> ToString[i, StandardForm]], 
  Print[ListLinePlot[data]]}, {i, testfiles}]

(*
Out[500]= {aspirina.txt, silicio.txt, silicio20.txt, silicio20luz.txt,
  tio2.txt, vidro.txt, vidro2.txt}
*)
```

> ```
> Import::nffil: File not found during Import. >> 
> ~/Desktop/TCOEM/Espetros Raman/aspirina.txt
> ```

etc.

The directory and file names are correct, so much so that when I try this directly by just typing the exact same directory I get the desired result.

Firstly, I changed the `FormatType` setting of `ToString[]` to `StandardForm` because the default (`OutputForm`) would give me an extra whitespace on either side of the full stop in the file names. Why does it do this?

Secondly, why is it that even when `Print[]` seems to indicate the directory is correct I get the exception saying the file cannot be found during Import?

I specifically did not format the names of the files in the testfiles list individually as strings (using "" around each one) to allow for the case where I have hundreds of such files and just want to copy and paste their names via whatever file manager I happen to be using.

Any help will be greatly appreciated!

Comment: It's usually easier to let *Mathematica* find the files, as in VLC's answer, but if you have to paste filenames from the clipboard you can paste between two quote marks to get a single long string, and use `StringSplit` to break it into individual filenames.

Comment: Good to know thanks :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Filenames are always strings. What you do when you use something like `aspirina.txt` without quotes is, you use the `Dot` operator (which is `.` in infix) to and give the two variables `aspirina` and `txt` as input.

Please try

```
testfiles = {"aspirina.txt", "silicio.txt", "silicio20.txt", "silicio20luz.txt", 
"tio2.txt", "vidro.txt", "vidro2.txt"};

Do[{data = Import[path <> i, {"Table"}], 
  Print[path <> i], 
  Print[ListLinePlot[data]]}, {i, testfiles}]
```

Comment: I had not realised Dot existed and that it is equivalent to . Thank you.

Answer (score 4):

You don't need to copy and paste the names of your files. If all the files you want to import are in a specific directory you can just import them directly from that directory.

You first need to define where your directory is by using `SetDirectory`. Then you can get the list of your files:

```
filesToImport = ToFileName[Directory[], #] & /@ FileNames["*.txt"]
```

This line will give you a list of all the paths to the files within the directory.

Comment: This appears to be an altogether more sensible approach. Thanks!